# Identifying the linear and non-linear portions of a curve

Tags: calculus

Background:  trying to determine the linear and non-linear sections of stress-strain curves in Material Science.  I am try to understand if you can determine mathematically, the point at which a stress-strain curve switches from the elastic (linear) to plastic (non-linear) regions.

I am neither a mathematician nor engineer but have tried to research this problem. Based on that research it seems like this is a differential calculus question where that point would be the point in which the slope of the line changes. Am in in the ballpark on this?

Specific math question:  Can you determine a point (or points) on a any curve where that curve transitions form linear to non-linear?  If so, what technique is used?

Try to determine the (x,y) of point labeled 1 in attached image.

[From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiHzJ.png)

Thanks, 
--Bob

Comment: Hey Bob! Do you know the whole curve exactly or just observations of it (e.g. a picture or similar)? In first case it would result from the definition of the curve, in the latter it would lay in the area between approximation theory and statistics

Comment: Thanks Nico.  Just updated my original post.  Hope this helps to clarify my question.  First time on this board.  :-)